# can i copy a class object into a byte array?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Below is the code of a class whom i created an object and want to copy it to a bytes array so that it can be sent over the udp network.

```
unit client_info;

interface
uses
sysutils,windows;
type
 Tclient = class
     public
   Fexternal_ip: string;
   Fexternal_port:word;
   Finternal_ip: string;
   Finternal_port:word;
   Fusername:string;

   constructor create(Ae_ip:string;Ae_port:word;Ai_ip:string;Ai_port:word;Ausername:string);


 end;


implementation

constructor Tclient.create(Ae_ip:string;Ae_port:word;Ai_ip:string;Ai_port:word;Ausername:string);
begin

Fexternal_ip:=Ae_ip;
Fexternal_port:=Ae_port;
Finternal_ip:=Ai_ip;
Finternal_port:=Ai_port;
Fusername:=Ausername;

end;

end.



implementation

    user:=tclient.create(ex_ip,ex_port,s,0,''); // client profile

       move(user,buffer[0],length(buffer));
```

would it be correct using move command?

Comment: That's a bad idea, you'd be tightly coupling both systems.

Comment: please provide some solution i need that for nat bypass.

Comment: serialize the object to a notation that is better suitable for transport, like XML or JSon. That way the two systems are not tightly coupled by some specific binary format.

Comment: As @GolezTrol, suggests. You do not need it. More to the point you do not want it. Just pass the four values in some known format. Create an Instance of of something (could be your TClient) and pass the values to the constructor. Your solution is just a fragile tin of bugs.